# Save credentials via WNetAddConection API

Tags: c#, winapi, wnet

I'm creating a desktop app in C# using [aejw](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6847/Map-Network-Drive-API) API. Then i have to map a persistent network drive connection with stored authentication.

There is a sample code i using without effect. The code maps share succesfully, but dont store a password in Credential Manager. It is posssible to take the effect(store password) what i want using 'Runtime.InteropServices'

```
NetworkDrive nd = new NetworkDrive();
             nd.LocalDrive = "Y:";
             nd.Persistent = true;
             nd.SaveCredentials = true;
             nd.ShareName = @"\\server\share";
             nd.MapDrive(username, password);
```

Comment: That code P/Invokes with CONNECT_CMD_SAVECRED but you also need to prompt for credentials and even then it is missing a required flag.

Comment: @Anders you mean flag 'connect_cmd_savecred' works only when operating system prompts for a credential ? So there is any other way to save credentials in Credential Manager which can be used to authentication for network share ?

Comment: That is what MSDN says about that flag, I don't know if it is true.

Comment: @Anders You were right. But I would avoid any prompts for user.

Comment: You would have to write the cred. yourself then. Perhaps debug net.exe to see exactly what it does.